# Update to Xcode 8.1: Can no longer convert JSON data of type AnyObject to expected Type

Tags: json, swift, swift3

When receiving a dictionary [String:AnyObject] my parsing now fails on trivial stuff. When I used to be able to convert, for example the following:

the model is simply:

```
class Invoice:NSObject {
    var id:String
    var amount:Float

    init?(json: [String:AnyObject]) {
        if let id = json["id"] as? String {
            self.id = id 
        }
        if let amount = json["amount"] as? Float {
            self.amount = amount
        }
    }
}
```

The input is for example: ["id":"1", "amount":0] or ["id":"1", "amount":4] or ["id":"1", "amount":4.50]

As of XCode 8.1 my models now return nil and I cannot see why. Did 8.1 change casting or something?

Comment: Your init looks fine, could perhaps be something to do with your class/struct itself?

Comment: I reverted back to Xcode 8 and the code works just fine. So 8.1 did change something. I added the model, but it's all basic stuff.

Comment: Also what's a `JSONDictionary`? That something you made?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typealias for [String:AnyObject] - edited

Comment: Sorry, I was scoping my question. The float is the one that now fails.

Comment: @TomWolters I think you'll have to add some `else` statements for your `if let` unwrapping in case the type casting fails. Either that or set default values for the `id` and `amount` properties

Answer (score 1):

> Changing my 'if let' works.

```
var amount:Double
```

**Xcode 8.0**

```
if let amount = json["amount"] as? Float {
   self.amount = amount
}
```

**Xcode 8.1**

```
if let amount = json["amount"] as? NSNumber {
   self.amount = amount.doubleValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class's `init` method won't work in this case, as there is a chance that some of its properties won't be initialised due to the unwrapping not working in your `if let` statements.

So you would have to set some defaults for those properties:

```
var id: String = ""
var amount: Float = 0
```

Another way is to add an else case for the unwrapping:

```
if let amount = json["amount"] as? Float {
    self.amount = amount
} else {
    amount = 0
}
```

Which is basically the same as setting a default like we did before, so it would be more clear to leave it as the first way described above.

Or, more easily, if you don't want to have defaults for a specific property, you'd have to make it an optional, e.g.

```
var id: String?
```

Comment: Exactly, the unwrapping is not working in my if let statements. It does work in all other versions of xcode, but xcode 8.1.